# Bluetooth Headphones Volume Too Low

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

The Samsung Galaxy Buds have built-in volume and when connecting to a new device are not at full volume. The manufacturer's way to increase volume is to install an app on your mobile device called 'Samsung Wear' which enables additional features of your device. One feature is increasing or decreasing the volume by enabling the long-press function on the buds to increase the volume. Then long-pressing the right ear bud to increase the volume, long-pressing the left ear bud will decrease the volume. That long-press feature doesn't work when connected to Ubuntu.

FYI, if any of this info is relevant to those who can't test these things: The buds themselves can be used individually, so if one dies you can grab the other bud. Grabbing them out of the charging case will turn them on and they'll auto-connect to the last connected BT device if available, etc. Single, Double, and Triple pressing the ear bud does work to pause/next/previous track. The only functions that are configurable is the long press function, and only in their app.

I came across some instructions to increase the volume for the Apple Airpods https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Apple_Airpods_have_low_volume

Do you think it's safe to test that fix or is there a better route to increase the volume on these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me:
- Try to activate experimental function which allows to increase and decrease volume by tapping you right and left headphone (use Galaxy Wear app for that)
- Configure and restart your bluetooth service ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Apple_Airpods_have_low_volume)
- Pair device and increase volume via tapping

Comment: thanks, this worked for me on a Bose QC35 ii headset. I used the volume buttons on the headset and it increased the volume without changing anything on the Linux side.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Ive been reading all the apparent solutions, editing configs, restarting etc etc. Almost gave up and went back to wired headphone. Agreed, solution was to set the touch settings to volume in the gear app then reconnect to laptop. Now maxed out the volume and can now control volume from my OS

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, but noticed that every time I connected to the headphones the maximum volume available would be different. e.g. 100% on the laptop could be either quiet or loud with the same test audio.

Also it didn't matter whether it was headphones or a portable BT speaker. Same issue.

I use my bluetooth headset with both my android phone and my Pop!OS system. Pop!OS uses pulseaudio like Ubuntu. So, I'm often disconnecting from one device and connecting to another.

**Here's how I solved it:**

1. Connect the headphones to my android phone.
2. Start some audio playing over the headphones.
3. Increase the volume to maximum using the buttons on the headphones, or via the phone if the speaker doesn't have volume buttons.
4. Disconnect the headphones from the phone.
5. Connect the headphones to the computer.

**Now the maximum perceived volume via the OS is the same as for the phone.**

It seems that the bluetooth functionality on the computer is not able to correctly read the current volume setting on the speakers device, or may use a different scaling factor. The, on connection, it makes some assumption about the volume state on the speakers that is not correct.

This is all anecdotal at this point, but I will post this elsewhere because there are a lot of people stating a similar problem.

Comment: I have the exact same problem (with a different headset) and independently found the same solution: Before I connect my headset to my computer, I connect it to my phone and raise the volume there. I have to assume that this Ubuntu bug only affects some headsets, else everyone would be complaining about it? Really annoying.

Comment: Perfect solution with Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

Install GalaxyBudsClient and in touchpad enable Double-tap earbud edge to turn the volume down or up.
https://github.com/ThePBone/GalaxyBudsClient

Answer (score 0):

On my BoseQC35 I had the low sound issue; apparently the Bluetooth driver does not sync audio levels at all. There is one audio level on the speakers, and another audio level inside Ubuntu.

All I had to do was turn up the volume on the speakers themselves while connected through Bluetooth to the Ubuntu PC.